# android set state color list programatically

Tags: android, layout, selector

I am trying to create a user themeable app. I have linearlayouts which are clickable and I need to set the selector programatically when the layouts are added to the parent view. However the following code throws a NoSuchMetod exception when I set v.SetBackground().

Where am I going wrong?

```
           LinearLayout d = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_psudo_launcheritem, null);             

            ColorDrawable clrBase = new ColorDrawable();
            clrBase.setColor(gCurrentTheme.Colours.Backgrounds.MenuItem);
            ColorDrawable clrSelect = new ColorDrawable();
            clrSelect.setColor(gCurrentTheme.Colours.Backgrounds.MenuItem_Select);
            ColorDrawable clrPress = new ColorDrawable();
            clrPress.setColor(gCurrentTheme.Colours.Backgrounds.MenuItem_Press);

            StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
            states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled}, clrBase);
            states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_selected}, clrSelect);
            states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, clrPress);

       //This line causes a NoSuchMethod exception!
            v.setBackground(states);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`View.setBackgroud` has been introduce in `api level 16` and replaceB  `setBackgroundDrawable` (it is deprecated since `API 16`) If the mobile where you are running the above code as an `API` level lower than 16 you have to use `setBackgroundDrawable`

Comment: hmm I thought I'd tried that... appears not! Thanks it's working now